# How to create new table in msdb or master in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to create table in `MSDB` and store some binary data in it.

How can do this?

thanks

Comment: Why? Why do you want to mess with the system databases?

Comment: The msdb database is used by SQL Server Agent for scheduling alerts and jobs and by other features such as SQL Server Management Studio, Service Broker and Database Mail. Why do you want to create a table there? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have adequate permissions, you can create tables in msdb and master the same way you create tables in any user database. It can be done [using Transact-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) or using the visual tools in SQL Server Management Studio.

However, as the commenters above have noted, it is usually not a good idea to make changes to the system databases. Microsoft reserves the right to make any and all changes to those databases as they roll out new software updates and service packs. That could adversely affect your solution. Conversely, your changes may have an adverse effect on the system databases and the processes and functionality they support.

I recommend storing the data in a separate user database.

Comment: thanks a lot Brian.  i want to create and fill system table in MASTER or MSDB databases. i want to do it for more security